# Dynamically Loading Camel Processor depending on a property in message body or header

Tags: java, apache-camel, wildfly-10

I'm working on finding a solution to route a message through a processor dynamically decided at the runtime depending on some attibute on message header or body.

Let's say I have two message Processors (eg : `Type1RequestProcessor`, `Type2RequestProcessor`) as mentioned below.

What I want to do is executing either `Type1RequestProcessor` or `Type2RequestProcesso`r dynamically decided using a property in the message header ot body.(Here I don't want to create multiple routers per Processor types.)

I tried as mentioned below (passing typeId in header). But it obviously gives below error saying `No bean could be found in the registry for: ${header.messageId}RequestProcessor of type: org.apache.camel.Processor`.

**HTTPRouter.java**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.cdi.ContextName;

@ApplicationScoped
@ContextName("camel-cdi-context")
public class HTTPRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:oneRouter")
        .process("${header.typeId}RequestProcessor")
        .to("direct:anotherRouter");
    }
}
```

**Error :**

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route19 at: >>> process[ref:${header.messageId}RequestProcessor] <<< in route: Route(route19)[[From[direct:oneRouter]] -> [process[ref:${he... because of No bean could be found in the registry for: ${header.messageId}RequestProcessor of type: org.apache.camel.Processor
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1298)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:204)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3540)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3271)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:202)
```

I tried with the bean component also but the result is same.

Can anyone give a little hand here? 
How to load the Processors dynamically?

**Type1RequestProcessor.java**

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

public class Type1RequestProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        // Do Type1 process implementation

    }

}
```

**Type2RequestProcessor.java**

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

public class Type2RequestProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        // Do Type2 process implementation

    }

}
```

**Note :** I have plan B of loading these implementation dynamically within a process method in router itself (Anonymous Inner Class). But I'm still looking for this since it will perfectly suit what I'm looking for.

- Camel Version : 2.19.2
- WildFly version : 10.1.0
- Camel Patch Version :
  wildfly-camel-patch-4.9.0

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Thanx Claus Ibsen, but what I'm looking for is dynamically loading the processor. Not calling URI dynamically. If i need to call URI dynamically I could use toD() also since I'm using camel 2.19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic expression language cannot be used inside process method, but you can annotate your Processors with `@Named` to make it available in CDI registry. Then invoke it with bean component using `.toD(bean:${header.typeId}RequestProcessor)` <del>or directly with `.toD(${header.typeId}RequestProcessor)`</del>.

Please note Named bean name translates to class name in camelCase by default. You can customize this behavior with `@Named("Type1RequestProcessor")`.

Comment: Hi Bedla, with bean: this is working nicely as expected. I was so closed to it. But make it visible to me. Thanks a lot! BTW, directly invoking without the bean: component is not working (Error : org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: Type1RequestProcessor due to: uri: Type1RequestProcessor bean: com.temp.Type1RequestProcessor@359d227f could not be converted to an Endpoint